# Как использовать функцию malloc()?

Tags: c

`malloc()` резервирует некоторый участок памяти, но как я могу этот участок использовать? Есть два варианта, но если подумать логически, ни один не подходит.

```
int *ptr=malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
```

Либо:

```
int *ptr; 
ptr=malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
```

В первом варианте значение адреса выделенного участка будет присвоено переменной, на которую указывает `*ptr`. А во втором примере это значение будет присвоено самому указателю, хотя ему надо присваивать адрес какой-либо переменной. Ну или я в целом неправильно понял концепцию выделения памяти и функции `malloc()`.

Comment: Приведенные вами куски кода идентичны и действуют вот так - "значение адреса выделенного участка присвоится переменной ptr." 

Вы плохо понимаете, как работать с указателями. Читайте учебник, видимо, сначала.

Comment: Ладно, я понял что было не так. Указатель указывает на адрес выделенного участка, так и должно быть. Но вопрос остался: как записать что-то в этот выделенный участок памяти? Вот так, например, пойдёт? `int *ptr=malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
    *ptr=10;`

Comment: @KirovReporting если грубо, после вызова malloc та или иная структура данных считается инициализированной в памяти, и остается только воспользоваться ей. В случае с указателями на структуры можно писать напрямую в свойства,в случае с интом, насколько помню (а помню плохо), надо записать в разыменованный указатель.

Comment: В Вашем примере очень странный параметр у функции malloc. Параметром должно быть положительное число — сколько памяти выделить в байтах. Вы передаёте константу, которая содержит размер указателя (4 байта для 32-битных машин и 8 байт для 64-битных машин). Выделение таких небольших областей памяти неэффективно, поскольку каждый выделенный блок имеет заголовок, который сам может занимать 8-16 байт (в зависимости от реализации). Но если Вы именно хотите выделить область памяти размером с указатель, пишите `sizeof(void*)`, так будет прозрачнее.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция `maloc()` выделяет память, размер которой определяется аргументом и возвращает указатель на эту память. Ваши два варианта идентичны и дело только в строчках кода в этих вариантах. Записать в вашу ptr значения можно с помощью разименования указателя: ну например `*ptr = 5;`.

Comment: Точно, я в комменте выше тоже так написал, значит понял, спасибо.

Comment: Разминирование указателя? Это точно так называется?

Comment: извините, исправил